# Qt Building MYSQL Driver with MSVC19 Complier

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, visual-c++

I am trying to build MYSQL drivers with MSVC2019 Compiler without success. I have reviewed all the different directives including Qt Docs in vain. I have previously built drivers for MinGW without a hassle and all projects with MinGW as a compiler on my machine are currently connecting to the MYSQL database. Now this new project requires that I use DLL compiled with MSVC and specifically am required to use MSVC 32bits. Here's the output from the console

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.2.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community>C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019\bin\qtenv2.bat
Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!

C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019>cd C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers

C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="D:/Qt/Apps/connectors/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="D:/Qt/Apps/connectors/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32/lib"

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'nmake'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'nmake install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.


C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.32.31332.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd sqlite\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite\sqlite.pro ) && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.32.31332.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.32.31332.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>nmake sub-mysql

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.32.31332.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'sub-mysql'
Stop.

C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>
```

I also got some errors in the config file:

> Project ERROR: msvc-version.conf loaded but QMAKE_MSC_VER isn't set.

Comment: As you can see qmake does not find your mysql stuff - the output after the first call is very clear about this. Please show in the config logs as described in the documentation why. I would gues because Qt was build with 64bits but you're using the 32 bit connector libs.

Comment: Yes i wanted to keep it 32bit because am compiling with MSVC 32 bit as well as the project am working on. Let me try with 64bit connector.

Comment: @chehrlic I got same results even when I changed the connectors. Could Visual Studio be a problem since its 2022. Do I have to install MSVC 2019?

Comment: And you still did not look in the config logs to see why it was not found...

Answer (score 0):

The [CodeMonkey68](https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/) built almost all drivers for MYSQL [here](https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases) and [Gan](https://www.youtube.com/user/SuperAfsd) created a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeErME39zvw) explaining how to use these drivers. I used his instructions and I was able to connect to the database using MSVC2019 32bits and 64bits. Its a matter of understanding the version of your Compiler/Kit and then download the right driver from the site.

Comment: Three months later, Gan's tutorial was removed from Youtube but all you need to do is to copy both release and debug .dll files that are contained then paste them into plugin folder within the qt install folder (i.e. on windows C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019\plugins\sqldrivers)